# Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined manual modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I installed this particular js plugin that lets you emulate some of the chrome like tab interface that supports dragging, closing and opening of the tabs.
https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/ui.tabs.overflowResize/master/demo/index.html

unfortunately, i ran into some problem after installing it, it kept printed on the console.

```
Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
```

Turns out that, it was because i was loading the tab ui scripts before the jquery.UI gets loaded to the Dom, so i copy pasted all the tab ui scripts to the one that loads after the jquery ui does.

So, finally the dragging function of the tabs work. but still missing proper opening and closing functions.(try clicking on the button below the tabs on the live site)

could anyone please take a look at this particular scripts and see if there's anyway i can manually modify the script to work on my website?

here is the live site: http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/

Comment: post your code here, so that we can evaluate

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can read these two posts and then came back to edit the question with a correct text: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude but what if there's no code to post? i mean, if you mean by me having to post all the js scripts that describes the whole function of the plugin, it can take pages to paste. can you be more specific what i need to do?

Comment: It's easy to provide a working example. But that needs to be minimal. Just read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it explains perfectly, better than I can explain you in a comment. You need to provide an snippet or a jsfiddle if it's easiest to you reproducing the problem you have. Doesn't matter how many lines of code there is, we cannot see your code with a crystal ball.

Comment: Note that you grow 2 votes to close this topic, it means that there's more people that have the same opinion.

Comment: You will want to add a working example of the issue. When I view the site, I am unable to determine the problem. Can't help if we can't see what you have done or tried.

Comment: I have setup a Test Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ryhzwkph/

Comment: @Twisty thanks for the kind fiddle. when i tried, the images didn't load. but im afraid I have already solved the problem, turns out, the script was missing some $ in function(){.

Comment: @Twisty since we are in the right topic, can i ask you a one more question? how do i use html tags in side this tab opening function?  jQuery( '.tabpanel' ).tabs('add', 'tab title', 'contents '); the 3rd parameter is where the contents are inserted, but im afraid it doesn't support html tags. I contacted the original plugin maker, but he doesn't seem to know either or at least doesn't answer. can you help me out? im guessing it has something to do with the jquery UI, which im not familiar with.

Comment: @MarkKang Not exactly easy. Documentation is horrible. But if you pass HTML to the Content, it will pace it in the tab.

Comment: @MarkKang There is a bug in the `.tabs("add")` near Line 115: `var id = $( "<div>"+content+"</div>" ).appendTo( this.element.children(':last-child') ).uniqueId().attr('id');` This appends the `div` into the wrong child element.

Comment: @Twisty which line 115 are you refering to? in what file? and, what would you have me do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an obscure answer, in relationship to the comment about Adding Tabs. It does not exactly relate to the original question.

As I mentioned, there is a bug in `ui.tabs.overflowResize`, on line 115:

```
var id = $( "<div>"+content+"</div>" ).appendTo( this.element.children(':last-child') ).uniqueId().attr('id');
```

This appends the `content` to the wrong `div`. It will `.appendTo()` the last `div` and it should be using `.after()` so that it is added after the last `div`. You can see this in the [Demo](https://rawgit.com/adamjimenez/ui.tabs.overflowResize/master/demo/index.html) as well.

I created a small function to help fix this:

```
function addTab(obj, t, c) {
  // Fixes .tabs("add") bug
  // obj = Target Object
  // t = Tab Title
  // c = Tab Content
  $(obj).tabs("add", t, c);
  var h = $(".addTab").prev().find("a").attr("href");
  $(h).clone().appendTo(obj);
  $(h).remove();
}
```

This grabs the `div` and rescues it, appending it to the target object. You can see a full working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ryhzwkph/

**JQUERY UI**

```
function addTab(obj, t, c) {
  // Fixes .tabs("add") bug
  // obj = Target Object
  // t = Tab Title
  // c = Tab Content
  $(obj).tabs("add", t, c);
  var h = $(".addTab").prev().find("a").attr("href");
  $(h).clone().appendTo(obj);
  $(h).remove();
}

$(function() {
  $(".tabpanel").tabs({
      closable: true,
      addTab: true
    }).tabs('overflowResize')
    .find(".ui-tabs-nav").sortable({
      distance: 10
    });
  $(".addTab a").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
  });
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Add: function() {
        addTab($(".tabpanel"), $("#tab_title").val(), $("#tab_content").val());
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
      $("#dialog form")[0].reset();
    }
  });
  $("#dialog form").submit(function(e) {
    addTab($(".tabpanel"), $("#tab_title").val(), $("#tab_content").val());
    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Much of this was adapted from https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

**EDIT**

From the Demo examples, I had missed a small notation. This was not documented, but the author advises adding an extra `div`, like so:

```
<div class="tabpanel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="closable">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="ui-layout-content">
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see this at work here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ryhzwkph/10/

Comment: Cool!. im still very much a beginner in jquery. could you kindly tell me where  i can apply your tip? i put the scrips above right after the original ui js scripts in the jquery.ui.datepicker.js on the live website : http://lifeto.cafe24.com/xe/ and found it not working.

Comment: You came in like a shooting star, like an oasis that relives my thirst. I can't say enough, how much grateful i am that you are here. Thank you for your examples.

Comment: @MarkKang you would add this to the Script block you have starting at Line 93 in your index page. You will also need to add the various Plug-Ins before that script block.

Comment: but, what would you have me do if i  want to add html element such as <div class="class">something</div> to the content, without the prompt window that appears everytime i click on the new tab button? can you give me a tip?

Comment: @MarkKang I would advise reviewing the "documentation" on GitHub or asking a new question here at SO.

Comment: i understand. but can i just ask one more question that's rather related to this particular post? the 3rd parameter i think supports html from the beginning, and you are right about that the original js putting new tabs under the wrong place. but, even when i apply your solution, it still puts tabs under the last tab div not under the parent div (which is .tabpanel) could you illuminate why this is still hapenning? lifeto.cafe24.com/xe

Comment: @MarkKang I discussed this issue with the Plugin maker. See the **EDIT** to my answer. It fixes it the way the developer intended.